# VBA Issue in Web Scraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the Product name, SKU number, New and Old price from "https://www.crateandbarrel.me/en-ae/search/sofas" webpage using below VBA but nothing is fecthing. It seens the HTML data which was fetched doesn't contain the information which I am requesting.

```
Sub webscrape()

Dim HTTPreq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim url As String

url = "https://www.crateandbarrel.me/en-ae/search/sofas"

'send HTTP request to url

With HTTPreq
    .Open "Get", url, False
    .send
End With

response = HTTPreq.responseText

Debug.Print response

'read response html document

Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = response

r = 1
For Each divElement In html.getElementsByClassName("container container-grid")
    r = r + 1
    Set divCollection = divElement.all
    For Each element In divCollection
        If InStr(element.className, "name") > 0 Then Range("A" & r).Value = element.innerText
        If element.className = "col-itemSKU -inner" Then Range("B" & r).Value = element.innerText
        If element.className = "price state-cross" Then Range("D" & r).Value = element.innerText
        If element.className = "crossed-price" Then Range("E" & r).Value = element.innerText
   Next element
Next divElement

 
End Sub
```

Comment: Looking at the page, a lot of the data you want seems to be loaded dynamically. You (probably) wont be able to use XMLHTTP request. I would suggest using the InternetExplorer object (but its too old, and it doesnt work, tried it..) so you'll need something a bit more modern. selenium webdriver (edge or chrome) works well with excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the site's content is highly dynamic, it is loaded using an endpoint via ajax request, from which you can retrieve the JSON response by issuing an `XMLHTTP` request complying with the following method.

You can, however, fetch your required fields from the response using any json converter like [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)

```
Sub ScrapeContent()
    Const Url$ = "https://api.crateandbarrel.me/rest/v2/cab/products/search"
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument, sParams$
    Dim oHttp As Object
    
    sParams = "fields=products(code%2CearnablePoints%2Csellable%2Cname%2CurlName%2Csummary%2Cprice(FULL)%2Cbadges(code%2Cname)%2Cimages(DEFAULT)%2Cstock(FULL)%2CaverageRating%2CcrossedPrice(FULL)%2Ccategories(name%2Ccode%2Curl)%2Cswatches(FULL)%2Cvariants(FULL)%2CprimaryCategory(FULL))%2Cfacets%2Cpagination(DEFAULT)%2Csorts(DEFAULT)%2CfreeTextSearch&query=sofas&currentPage=1&pageSize=24&lang=en&curr=AED"

    Set Html = New HTMLDocument
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    With oHttp
        .Open "GET", Url & "?" & sParams, True
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send
        While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        MsgBox .responseText
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Guy's thank you so much, I was able to scrape the detials from there USA website which was not so dynamic. Now I need to fetch the images or image url atleast in excel.